# Topology - interval homeomorphic to another interval

Tags: general-topology, continuity

{a.}
Prove that any open interval $(a, b)$ is homeomorphic to the interval $(0, 1)$.

Define $f:(a, b) \to (0, 1)$ by $f(x)=(x-a)/(b-a)$, which is one-to-one and onto. Consider $f^{-1}:(0, 1) \to (a, b) := f^{-1}=a(-x)+a+bx$. We can see that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous functions. Therefore, the open intervals are homeomorphic.

{b.}
Prove that the ray $(a, \infty)$ is homeomorphic to $(1, \infty)$.

Define $f:(a, \infty) \to (1, \infty)$ by $f(x)=x/a$, which is one-to-one and onto. Consider $f^{-1}:(1, \infty) \to (a, \infty) := f^{-1}=ax$. We can see that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous functions. Therefore, the defined rays are homeomorphic.

{c.}
Prove that $(a, \infty)$ is homeomorphic to $(-\infty, -a)$.

Define $f:(a, \infty) \to (-\infty, -a)$ by $f(x)=-x$, which is one-to-one and onto. Consider $f^{-1}:(-\infty, -a) \to (a, \infty) := f^{-1}=x$. We can see that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous functions. Therefore, these open intervals are homeomorphic.

{d.}
Prove that R is homeomorphic to the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

Define $f:R \to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ by $f(x)=tan^{-1}x$, which is one-to-one and onto. Consider $f^{-1}:(-\pi/2, \pi/2) \to R := f^{-1}=tanx$. We can see that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous functions. Therefore, R is homeomorphic to the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

{e.}
Prove that $(1, \infty)$ is homeomorphic to $(0, 1)$.

Define $f:(1, \infty) \to (0, 1)$ by $f(x)=1/x$, which is one-to-one and onto. Consider $f^{-1}:(0, 1) \to (1, \infty) := f^{-1}=1/x$. We can see that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous functions. Therefore, these open intervals of the real line are homeomorphic.

We thus conclude that any two open intervals of the real line are homeomorphic.

{f.}
Prove that any two closed intervals of the real line are homeomorphic.
Define $f:[a, b] \to [c, d]$ by $f(x)=[(d-c)(x-a)/(b-a)]+c$, which is one-to-one and onto. Consider $f^{-1}:[c, d] \to [a, b] := f^{-1}=[(b-a)(x-a)/(d-c)]+a$. We can see that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous functions. Therefore, the closed, bounded intervals $[a, b]$ and $[c, d]$ of the real line are homeomorphic.

Comment: "...by showing there exists **a continuous** function s.t. *also* its inverse is continuous...", otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: As written (f) is false. Adding "bounded" makes it true, for example.

Comment: Could I correctly answer this by conditioning my answer on those requirements?

Comment: I don't know if you could, @SKA, but it would be possible.

Comment: The given proof for {b.} only holds when $a>0$. In general the more general case of $a \in \mathbb{R}$, you could use $f : x \mapsto x + 1 - a$.

Answer (score 2):

Either there's a mistake in the book or you've misunderstood the book's definition of "closed interval."  Certainly you're right that the line itself is not homeomorphic to a finite closed interval.  When this question says "closed interval" it means the interval [a,b] for real numbers a and b (not infinity).

(It's also worth thinking about whether you can prove that [0,1] and $(-\infty, +\infty)$ are not homeomorphic.)

Comment: This is directly from my book. I am assuming that the closed intervals need to be bounded. That is a necessary assumption before moving forward, correct? How would I go on after that?

Comment: I am fairly sure that $[0, 1]$ cannot be homeomorphic to $(-\infty, \infty)$, but don't know what would be the correct method of proving that.

Comment: @SKA: For bounded intervals you're going to approach is similarly to the way you approached the other ones: find an explicit continuous function going each way.  In this case you can use pretty simple functions.  As for why [0,1] and $(-\infty, \infty)$ are not homeomorphic, that's a bit trickier.  Once you know about compactness it's easy.  The first other approach I can think of is to identify some property that the endpoints have which no interior points can have.  For example, any connected open set containing 1 has the property that when you remove 1 its still connected.